# Java, tengo un problema creando una nueva instancia de una clase

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Buenas primero tengo esta clase User

```
package com.example.leaftime.rocketdefender;

/**  * Created by Leaftime on 04/11/2017.  */

public class User {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer score;

    public User(Integer id, String name, Integer score)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(Integer score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

que simplemente se encarga de los gets y sets de los id, nombre y puntaje en una base de datos sqlite que vienen integrada en android Studio y mi error es lo siguiente

```
package com.example.leaftime.rocketdefender;

import android.database.Cursor; import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase; import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; import android.os.Bundle; import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.leaftime.rocketdefender.utils.utility;

import java.lang.reflect.Array; import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;

public class HighscoreListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView highLIST;

    ArrayList<String> listInfo;
    ArrayList<User> listUsers;

    ConectionSQLiteHelper conn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_highscore_list);

        conn = new ConectionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), "bd users", null, 1);

        highLIST = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.highscoreList);

        getListPersons();

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listInfo);
        highLIST.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getListPersons()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();

        User user = null;
        listUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
        //select * from users
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + utility.TABLE_USER, null);

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            user = new User();
            user.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            user.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setScore(cursor.getInt(2));

            listUsers.add(user);
        }
        obtainList();
    }

    private void obtainList()
    {
        listInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < listUsers.size(); i++)
        {
            listInfo.add(listUsers.get(i).getId() + " - " + listUsers.get(i).getName());
        }
    } 
}
```

en esta parte declaro a user que viene de User() es null User user = null;

y para crear una instancia en un listview tengo esto

```
while(cursor.moveToNext())
{
            user = new User();
            user.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            user.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            user.setScore(cursor.getInt(2));

            listUsers.add(user); 

}
```

que lo que hace es crear cada uno de los items en list view pero al momento de llamarlo en user = new User() me pide que pase algun parametro, 
especificamente me dice User() in User cannot  be applied to : 
parameters arguments; ¿alguien me podria dar una pista de como solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que te sale, indica que estás creando "mal" el objeto User.
Lo que pasa, es que, cuando has declarado la clase User, has indicado en su constructor que tiene que recibir 3 parámetros:

```
public User(Integer id, String name, Integer score){...}
```

Estás indicando que para crear un objeto del tipo User tienes que pasarle un id, un name y un score.

Para arreglar esto, puedes pasarle los 3 parámetros que te pide o puedes crear un constructor al que no le pases argumentos (puedes declarar varios constructores dentro de una clase que reciben distintos parámetros)

```
public User(Integer id, String name, Integer score){...}
public User(){...}
```

Comment: muchas gracias amigo recien me doy cuenta de eso, y  una pregunta si lo declaro a User en la calse como public void User(los parametros), esto indicaria que no tengo que pasar necesariamente parametros?

Comment: no acabo de entender lo que me dices. Si creas un constructor con parámetros tienes que pasárselos, sino no. Lo que puedes hacer es tener varios constructores distintos dentro de una misma clase y poder crear un objeto User con o sin parámetros, pero para eso tienes que declarar varios constructores

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en la clase User sólo has declarado un constructor con tres  parámetros. Cuando creas una instancia de una clase tienes que utilizar uno de los constructores declarados en la clase. Añade, por lo tanto, en la clase User el constructor por defecto.

public User() {}

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

eso es por que si la constructora de User tiene 3 parametros al crearlo tienes que meter esos 3 parametros te quedaria asi:

Dentro de tu while serian dos lineas:

```
user = new User(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2));
listUsers.add(user);
```

PD: si te parece mas visible tambien puedes coger cursor.getInt(0) y las otras dos que tienes y meterlas en variables en vez de meterlas directamente en tu constructora. Asi quizas para alguna gente sea un codigo mas limpio y mas legible.